# Black spots on diffuse baking in cycles

Tags: baking

Around the collar there's black spots on baking result. I use low sampling of 50. But high sampling of 2000 doesn't fix the problem.
[image]

Meanwhile the original, just white.
[image]

If closed up, it seems that the black artifact comes from the black pixels of the darker face.
[image]

I tried to make larger image 2048x4096, but no vail

How to fix this?

Comment: Try to increase "Margin" value in baking options.

Comment: MMm... not working.  I have increase it from 3 to 6 to 15. The blacks don't come from the margin.